# Is it possible to create a detection oracle for all block cipher modes? -- ciphertext-only cryptanalysis

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, modes-of-operation

I have [made an ECB/CBC detection oracle](http://cryptopals.com/sets/2/challenges/11/), and am now trying to make a detection oracle that can differentiate between CBC/CFB/OFB/CTR/etc. I can already tell ECB apart from the others due to [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20723807/4225645).

My issue is that, other than ECB, the detection I know how to do at this point involves corrupting a bit of the ciphertext and analyzing the error propagation in the subsequent cleartext (like explained [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/39086/62107), and as read about in [Applied Cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/)). The problem of course is that this requires knowledge of the key and IV to be able to view the cleartext.

Is it possible to analyze only a ciphertext and determine the block cipher mode used to encrypt it?

Comment: If the ciphertext's length is not a multiple of the block size, you can rule out ECB, CBC, and PCBC.

Comment: You'll have a hard time to differentiate between CTR and OFB...